# How to move a point along the circle?

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a point $(x, y)$ inside a rectangle of size $(W, H)$. How to select a direction for that point, what would be equations whose solutions would give something like this:

[image]

A direction to the nearest clockwise point on inscribed circle (along one of the axes) if the point is inside and on a line that touches circle if point is outside?

Comment: What do you mean by “nearest clockwise point?”

Comment: @amd: by a nearest clockwise point here I mean a point on inscribed circle along one of the axes that is closest to the given point

Comment: Are there any cases in which you can solve the problem?  Which cases are giving you trouble?  What is the answer supposed to be if the point is at the center of the circle?

Comment: How is the course detrmined? Is there a rudder angle? Is the blue line be a sort of an asymptote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the circle have radius $R$ and be centered at the origin. Given $(x,y)$ let $\phi={\rm arg}(x,y)$ be its polar angle, determined up to $2\pi$. Then 
$${\rm arg}\,{\bf v}(x,y)=\left\{\eqalign{\left\lfloor{2\phi\over\pi}+{1\over2}\right\rfloor{\pi\over2}\qquad&\qquad\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<R)\cr
\phi+\pi\pm\arcsin{R\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}&\qquad\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>R)\ .\cr}\right.$$
A decision about the $\pm$ as well as some exception handling will be necessary.

Comment: What $arg$ means here?

Comment: See here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712565/formal-definition-for-angle-function/2712928#2712928