# Formal Definition for Angle Function

Tags: functions, angle

Which is the correct formal definition for the angle function $\theta(x,y)$ for a vector $(x,y)$ or complex number $x+iy$ with unit magnitude, such as $e^{i \theta}=x+iy$?

Inverse trigonometric functions do not map into the full circle.

In Matlab,

$\theta=\text{atan2}(x,y):x \in [-1,1], y \in [-1,1] \to \theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$

But i dont think this is a formal standard.

Comment: We know that $(r, \theta) \mapsto re^{i\theta}$ is a bijection $(0,\infty) \times (-\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, which induces the inverse function $(r,\theta) = (r(x,y), \theta(x, y))$. Given that $\theta$ is defined, we can exploit $\arctan$ to represent $\theta(x, y)$ in a piecewise manner.

Comment: Yes i am clear... what is not clear for me is which is the standard or best choice for doing that representation, for better numerical properties, etc.

Comment: Depends on the range of $\theta$. Taking the right hand side of the real axis as the base, the angle is just $\arctan(y/x)$ in the first quadrant and translations of $\arctan(y/x)$ by some multiple of $\pi$ for the other quadrants depending on the range of $\theta$.

Comment: @hyprfrcb: There is no "best" choice. You choose one of the available notions depending on how you want to use it. If you want $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi]$, then $\operatorname{atan2}$ is the usual choice. If you want $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$, then your explicit definition for $\theta$ would just involve $\arctan(y/x)$ for the first quadrant and suitable translations by $\pi$ for the other quadrants, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this article regarding the [Argument Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)), citing the last formula for the double angle tangent, as the most formal and numerically stable definition for the *argument* function, and hence, for the $\text{atan2}$ function i have been able to find so far:

$$
\text{atan2}(x,y)= 
\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}y \right) & y\ne0\\
0 & y=0, x>0\\
\pi & y=0, x<0\\
\text{undef.} & y=0, x=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 2):

It is a basic fact of analysis that there is no continuous real-valued "angle function" $\ \theta:\>\dot{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}$. Instead we have the *argument function*
$${\rm arg}:\quad\dot{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}/(2\pi{\mathbb Z})$$
that for each point $(x,y)\in\dot{\mathbb R}^2$ gives its polar angle modulo (or "up to multiples of")  $2\pi$. Even though this is not a real-valued function it has a well defined gradient
$$\nabla{\rm arg}(x,y)=\left({-y\over x^2+y^2},\>{x\over x^2+y^2}\right)\qquad\bigl((x,y)\in\dot{\mathbb R}^2\bigr)\ .$$
For many purposes it is sufficient to consider the *principal value of the argument*. It is defined by 
$${\rm Arg}(x,y):={\rm the}\bigl\{{\rm arg}(x,y)\>\cap\>]{-\pi},\pi[\>\bigr\}$$
 on $\dot{\mathbb R}^2$ with the negative $x$-axis removed. Note that people often write ${\rm arg}$ when actually ${\rm Arg}$ is meant. The connection with the inverse trigonometric function is as follows: When $x>0$ (and only then!) one has
$${\rm Arg}(x,y)=\arctan{y\over x}\qquad(x>0)\ .$$